# C# WPF Access XAML from external class without creating an Instance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have an XAML with codebehind, and an external cs.

These are the relevant lines:

XAML:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="FaceTrackingBasics.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FaceTrackingBasics"
    xmlns:ht="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf" 
    >

<Grid>
    <ht:BindableRotateManipulator x:Name="ARotation" Position="0 0 0"  
    Diameter="0.1"InnerDiameter="0.1" Axis="0 1 0" Color="Green" 
    Value="0" 
    TargetTransform="{Binding Transform, ElementName=model1}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class ShellView : Window
{

    public ShellView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public SomeMethod()
    {
        ARotation.Value = Value //The Value that I get from the external .cs
    }

}
```

External .cs:

```
public partial class FirstExternalClass : UserControl, IDisposable
{
    public class SecondExternalClass : DependencyObject, IDisposable
    {

        private float SomeFloat;

        public void ExternalMethod()
        {
            SomeFloat = SomeValue;   //This Method is being called regularly
                                     //this value is behing changend everytime
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what I need to do is to somehow bind the Value in the XAML to "SomeFloat" so that it changes whenever the value of "SomeFloat" changes.

I've tried to just call a Method in ShellView and give it the current value so that the Method then will change the Value in the XAML. I can only do this with a static Method in ShellView, and if it is static, I cant change the Value in the XAML.

I've tried to create an Instance of ShellView and then call the Non-Static Method, but I will get Errors.

I've tried Depency Object (Dependency Property).

I've tried MVVM.

Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Please learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the Value property to a relevant property in a ViewModel or something:

```
    <ht:BindableRotateManipulator x:Name="ARotation" Position="0 0 0"  
    Diameter="0.1"InnerDiameter="0.1" Axis="0 1 0" Color="Green" 
    Value="{Binding MyValue}" 
    TargetTransform="{Binding Transform, ElementName=model1}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _value;
    public double Value //or float, whatever
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    //... Implement INotifyPropertyChanged here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ok but now Im using the PropertyChangedEventHandler and it will only work with a string. How can I make it work with a float?

Comment: @user3030653 I don't understand your comment. `NotifyPropertyChange()` works with all types.